# Run shell file at time intervals

Tags: shell, unix, time, command, redhat

I want to open a device, and run a shell file every 30 minutes using a single command, however, this only as long as I am logged into the device (this device can be accessed remotely by multiple people sharing a sroot login, I do not want them to have this shell running)

Originally I found the `watch -n TIME` command, however it didn't work, it displayed incomplete information, here's how I ran it (60 for a minute, as I just wanted to test if it worked)

```
watch -n 60 /tmp/test.sh
```

I would like to know a way of achieving the same as using watch,  but that actually works for long outputs of certain `.sh` files.

- 1.

  ```
  while true; do COMMAND; sleep 2; done
  ```
- 2.

  ```
  * */4 * * *  /path-to-your-command
  ```

Those are other similar "solutions" I found, that either didn't work for long outputs or were "permanent" (with no clear indication as to how to stop them)

Also I can't install packages that are not on the device as it is not mine.

I know I'm putting it complicated, but thanks a lot!

Comment: I would use `cron` to schedule the job every 30 minutes, and modify the script to check whether you are logged in, and only do its 'real work' if you are.

Comment: that wouldn't help, as we all share the user, there's no distinction as to when "I" am the one logged in or some other guy, also the device does not belong to me.

Comment: Oh...interesting...then how on earth is your program going to know whether to run or not?  And how is it going to know what to do if both you and one of your colleagues are on the machine at the same time?  The shared login ID is a bad idea from the start — you've lost all trackability and accountability.